# Getting an abort trap:6 at compile time

Tags: c++, global-variables

Trying to build a c++ project and I'm getting a trap: 6 at compile time. I must be doing something wrong with memory allocation. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
//Dependency.h

namespace whatever{
class Dependency {
public:
    Dependency(std::function<void ()> const & func);

private:
    std::function<void ()> const call_back;
};

Dependency::Dependency(std::function<void ()> const & func){
            call_back = func;
}

extern Dependency * current;
extern int counter;
}
```

And here is the .cpp file

```
#include "Dependence.h"

namespace whatever {

    Dependency * current;
    int counter = 1;

}
```

I tried removing the assignment to counter, but that did not do anything. 
Here is the error message

```
*** [src/Dependence.o] Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Nothing you do should cause a crash at compile/link time. What compiler and OS are you using (versions for both). If it is reproducible by other people with the same system. Then file a bug against the compiler manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks Loki. I was using gcc 4.9. Switching to 4.8.1 solved all my problems. It's crazy how finicky this can all be.

Comment: Should there be an error on callback = func; in the constructor? Is this a compiler issue or me?

Comment: That's your error in the constructor. The member is const so it can be changed after it has been created. You should set call_back in the initializer list.